# Windows 8.1 lockscreen image not updating with script

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a script that runs when I log in that replaces the image file that I have my lockscreen set to with another image.
i.e. I have my lockscreen set to the image `Lock.jpg` and when I log in a script replaces `Lock.jpg` with some other image.
However when I restart the actual lockscreen keeps the old image.
How can I fix this?? 
I can provide the script if needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out with extensive googling that I had to replace the file
`LockScreen__1920_1080.jpg` in
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-21-x-x-x-1000\ReadOnly\LockScreen_B` and that successfully changed my lockscreen.